# auto correction last name with double name

Tags: php

I have a html form, where the user can write his / her own last name and send it to an php file, which checks if all is correct.

Now I would like to make an auto correction, for this case:

```
Last name: maX-poWEer
```

this should be corrected as follows

```
Max-Power
```

the first letters should be allways uppercase, and the others should be lowercase:

```
strtolower("maX-poWEer");
```

New Result:

```
max-power
```

But how can I realize the first letters of each name as uppercases?
ucwords() doenst work in this case

Comment: I would advise against doing that in the first place. It will mess up actual names like `McDonald` or `van Gogh`.

Comment: Are you asking how to correct people name's spelling or that's a typo on your side?

Comment: if its specifically for hyphenated surnames split by `-`, loop, to lower, join back https://3v4l.org/ZNt1b presuming the extra `E` is a typo

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the mb_convert_case() function, this function can handle utf-8 characters, which is useful when dealing with international names.

```
$name = "maX-poWEer";
$formatted_name = mb_convert_case($name, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");
echo $formatted_name; // Output: "Max-Poweer"
```

Comment: What's the use case here? This converts `O'Brian` to `O'brian`, `McDonald` to `Mcdonald`, `de las Eras` to `De Las Eras`... all of which are incorrect casing. I would trust my users to write their own names.